# Is it possible to animate multiple KML (gpx) routes in Google Earth

Tags: kml, google-earth, gpx

I would like to import multiple gpx files into Google Earth & animate them concurrently.  I've only been able to animate one at a time.

Comment: How would such a concurrent animation work? Keep all lines in view at the same time?

Comment: Yes it is. Other people are doing it successfully. [Here is one example](http://replayroutes.com/demo.html) (although it seems a bit buggy now, but still works in principle) [Here is another](http://racemyrace.com/race.php) (you might need to load a few different races before you get one you can load multiple 'racers') The first example was put up by a guy called Mark Williams for demonstration purposes so I presume it is ok to hack into his code. The second example is just so you can see it is possible with lots (unlimited?) different tracks.....

Comment: I've been trying to use kml somehow, but the instruction set for touring doesn't seem to support multiple placemarks.  The comment fromlifeIsGood pointed me in the direction of using JavaScript, and I'm now looking at samples like Monster MilkTruck and the like. Any advise or help would be appreciated. We are trying to build a sailboat racetracker using uploaded gpx files from their tracking apps.  Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i have been getting going on sailboat race tracking just like you want.

Progress so far is great -

1. using smartphones as the .gpx data loggers on each boat ('GPS Essentials' for android and 'MyTracks' (NOT 'Mapmytracks') for iphone, both free.
2. At the end of the race we email the .gpx files which are imported into GoogEarth via tools/GPS/import.  because they are all on satellite time, the concurrence is perfect and automatic.
3. Each of the tracks appears in the temporary places window, where they can be renamed, path + icon colour changed an so on.
4. Move (by dragging) each boats file to one folder for this race. Create a "tour" of them and then right click the parent folder to email out a .kmz of the whole show.

spectacular.

Comment: That's great, can you get the tracks to animate at the same time?  I found an app called **animaps** which allows you to put together the animations.  Check it out;
http://www.animaps.com/pb/1702005/8671/RaceTracker07

Let's keep in touch.

Chris Lamb

Comment: Yes. and PERFECTLY at the same time because they are all on satellite time. I just had a look at animaps. its good, but i can't see a way of moving the camera (the map around) once its animated. its more like a movie in plan. It seems to me that Goog.Earth as the interface is simpler, plus there is much more dynamism (eg camera tracking) and flexibility (eg to view things from different view points) in Goog.E. So where are you up to with getting yours on line? Happy to help share what i've done, if it's needed...

Comment: Thanks Dav-o,  I'm still looking at similar implementations, and evaluating.  I'm an Xcode programmer, but I think this should be web based, so I'm not sure what the code should be written in.  I still don't see how GE & KML allow multiple tracks to animate concurrently.  I'd really like to discuss this more with you.  Can we take this off the forum?  My email is CPLamb@Pacbell.net in Santa Cruz, CA.  Contact me any time & we can talk about it.  Cheers, CPL